# After form Validation enable submit button and if click submit button open modal popup using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just have the small problem.. 1st of all im new to jQuery.. im a learner..

So, here i create a small form like 2 dropdowns, i just try to validate and when all validation's done, the submit button goes to enable, after
clicking the submit button the success modal comes to open..

i just try my way, but its not..

```js
jQuery("#accMergebtn").prop('disabled', true);

var toValidate = jQuery('#frm_acc', '#to_acc'),
  valid = false;
toValidate.keyup(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).val().length > 0) {
    jQuery(this).data('valid', true);
  } else {
    jQuery(this).data('valid', false);
  }
  toValidate.each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).data('valid') == true) {
      valid = true;
    } else {
      valid = false;
    }
  });
  if (valid === true) {
    jQuery("#accMergebtn").prop('disabled', false);

    $('#accloading').modal('show');
  } else {
    jQuery("#accMergebtn").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#accMergebtn").click(function() {
    $('#accloading').modal('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="contactForm">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- From Account name -->
    <div class="form-group col-6" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <label class="col-sm-6 control-label p-sm-0 acc-merge" for="frm_acc">Text from:*</label>
      <select class="form-control select-data .has-success" name="frm_account" id="frm_acc" required>
        <option value="">Choose an items</option>
        <option value="1">Plumz</option>
        <option value="2">Plumz2</option>
        <option value="3">Plumz3</option>
        <option value="4">Plumz4</option>
        <option value="5">Plumz5</option>
      </select>
      <div class="input-group col-sm-6 p-sm-0 form-group"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- To account name -->
    <div class="form-group col-6" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <label class="col-sm-6 control-label p-sm-0 acc-merge" for="to_acc">Text to:*</label>
      <select class="form-control select-data .has-success" name="to_account" id="to_acc" required>
        <option value="">Choose an items</option>
        <option value="1">Plumz</option>
        <option value="2">Plumz2</option>
        <option value="3">Plumz3</option>
        <option value="4">Plumz4</option>
        <option value="5">Plumz5</option>
      </select>
      <div class="input-group col-sm-6 p-sm-0 form-group"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Submit Button -->

  <div class="form-group ml-auto mt-2 mb-0">
    <div class="col-md-12 stockform_submit" id="">
      <button type="submit" class="btn add-btn submit-btn" id="accMergebtn">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default reset-btn stock_rst" style="left: 0%" id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="accloading" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal_load">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="./img/loading.gif" alt="Please Wait" class="load_icon">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

**[Here is my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/rbdqusaf/)**

> I just want after all validations done enable submit button and if submit button click open modal popups..

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery("#accMergebtn").prop('disabled', true);

var toValidate = "#frm_acc,#to_acc";
  valid = false;
 $(toValidate).change(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).val().length > 0) {
    jQuery(this).data('valid', true);
  } else {
    jQuery(this).data('valid', false);
  }
   $(toValidate).each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).data('valid') == true) {
      valid = true;
    } else {
      valid = false;
    }
  });
  if (valid === true) {
    jQuery("#accMergebtn").prop('disabled', false);

    //$('#accloading').show();
  } else {
    jQuery("#accMergebtn").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});

  function show() {

    event.preventDefault();
    alert('show');
    $('#accloading').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="contactForm">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- From Account name -->
    <div class="form-group col-6" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <label class="col-sm-6 control-label p-sm-0 acc-merge" for="frm_acc">Text from:*</label>
      <select class="form-control select-data .has-success" name="frm_account" id="frm_acc" required>
        <option value="">Choose an items</option>
        <option value="1">Plumz</option>
        <option value="2">Plumz2</option>
        <option value="3">Plumz3</option>
        <option value="4">Plumz4</option>
        <option value="5">Plumz5</option>
      </select>
      <div class="input-group col-sm-6 p-sm-0 form-group"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- To account name -->
    <div class="form-group col-6" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <label class="col-sm-6 control-label p-sm-0 acc-merge" for="to_acc">Text to:*</label>
      <select class="form-control select-data .has-success" name="to_account" id="to_acc" required>
        <option value="">Choose an items</option>
        <option value="1">Plumz</option>
        <option value="2">Plumz2</option>
        <option value="3">Plumz3</option>
        <option value="4">Plumz4</option>
        <option value="5">Plumz5</option>
      </select>
      <div class="input-group col-sm-6 p-sm-0 form-group"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Submit Button -->

  <div class="form-group ml-auto mt-2 mb-0">
    <div class="col-md-12 stockform_submit" id="">
      <button type="submit" class="btn add-btn submit-btn" id="accMergebtn" onclick="show()">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default reset-btn stock_rst" style="left: 0%" id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="accloading" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal_load">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="./img/loading.gif" alt="Please Wait" class="load_icon">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Whats the issue?? please elaborate.

Comment: No errors sir, but if i click submit button page only refreshed, not showing modal popup sir.

Comment: add  event.preventDefault() to prevent from page refresh.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/rbdqusaf/  here my code sir, plz help me, to validate the 2 dropdowns and after validation done, click submit button after it shows modal popup..

Comment: Just do this :
var toValidate =  "#frm_acc,#to_acc";
  valid = false;
$(toValidate).change(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).val().length > 0) {
    jQuery(this).data('valid', true);
  } else {
    jQuery(this).data('valid', false);
  }
  $(toValidate).each(function()

Comment: ist working fine sir, but modal popup only the problem.. now my problem is, popup will not showing after validation form, insted of when i select one dropdown (another one is not selected) and click submit the modal will came and showing..

Comment: i want to show the modal, that two dropdowns are selected after click submit the modal wants to come..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200800/discussion-between-abhishek-and-joe).